# Authentization agains Samba4 domain controler and not working kinit

Tags: kerberos, pam, winbind, samba4

I've a problem with Samba 4 and Kerberos. If I call `kinit`, it writes *Client not found in Kerberos database while getting initial credentials*. I find out, that the Kerberos works with user name only, but the system identifies all domain users with the domain name and backslash as prefix and Kerberos doesn't like it.

```
$ ssh user@machine #I don't need the domain name while logging in
DOMAIN\user@machine$ kinit
# does not work
DOMAIN\user@machine$ kinit DOMAIN\user
# does work neither
DOMAIN\user@machine$ kinit user
# works
DOMAIN\user@machine$ id
uid=2010(DOMAIN\user) gid=100(users) skupiny=100(users)
DOMAIN\user@machine$ getent passwd
# all domain users prefixed with 'DOMAIN\'
```

The same applies on list of files printed by `ls -l`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 DOMAIN\user users 3392 pro 19 14:46 filename
```

But when I've look at [Samba Wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba4/Winbind#Testing_2), they have user name printed by the `command getent passwd` without the domain name.

```
getent passwd
...
Administrator:x:0:100::/home/MATWS/Administrator:/bin/bash
```

I thing, that this may cause, that `kinit` does not work and the user has no tickets after login. But I don't know, how to get rid of the domain name prefix, what's wrong or what I'm missing in my configuration.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue where `$ kinit` produces `kinit: Client 'ADUsername@AD.EXAMPLE.COM' not found in Kerberos database while getting initial credentials`. Did you have any luck?